# avoiding loopback SAs w/ strongswan transport-mode IPv6 "trap-any"-style configuration for local subnet

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I have a StrongSWAN configuration inspired by [the `trap-any` test case](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/trap-any/):

```
conn %default
        ikelifetime=60m
        keylife=20m
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=1

conn lan
        right=%any
        leftsubnet=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::/64
        rightsubnet=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::/64
        type=transport
        authby=psk
        auto=route
```

This automatically negotiates a SA with any system on my local subnet I try to connect with; in general, it's doing the Right Thing.

However, when I multicast to my whole subnet:

```
ping6 -I fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234 ff02::1
```

...not only do I get responses from, and set up security associations with, the other systems (yay!), but I have two separate security associations generated communicating with *the local host itself*, with `fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234` as both initiator and responder.

---

My first thought was to avoid this like so:

```
conn local
       type=passthrough
       left=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234
       right=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234
```

...but that doesn't actually prevent the loopback connections.

---

By contrast, with:

```
conn local
        type=passthrough
        right=%any
        rightsubnet=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234/128
```

...no security associations are established *at all*.

---

How can I avoid SAs for local traffic in this mode?

Answer (score 0):

Lessons learned:

- Define *both* `leftsubnet` and `rightsubnet`
- Don't forget `auto=route` even for a `passthrough` connection.

Thus:

```
conn local
        type=passthrough
        right=%any
        leftsubnet=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234/128
        rightsubnet=fd12:3456:7890:abcd::1234/128
        auto=route
```

Many thanks to Thermi in the #strongswan IRC channel.